# Acessing object through object array

Tags: c#, object

I want to learn classes atm and here is what I came up with:

Class level to create a level. This class has an object array that fills itself with rooms (raeume) which is the other class. Now, I want to access the objects in the object array from room, after I inserted them. Here is what I want to type:

```
wohnung.rooms[i].raumname.toString();
```

Here are the two classes

```
class raum
{
    static object[] o_nebenraum = new object[3]; //N-O-S-W
    static string s_raumname = "";
    public object[] nebenraume
    {
        get
        {
            return o_nebenraum;
        }
        set
        {
            o_nebenraum = value;
        }
    }
    public string raumname
    {
        get
        {
            return s_raumname;
        }
        set
        {
            s_raumname = value;
        }
    }
}

class level
{
    static object[] o_rooms = new object[100];

    public object[] rooms
    {
        get
        {
            return o_rooms; 
        }
        set
        {
            o_rooms = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I set everything up.

```
level wohnung = new level();
        raum keller = new raum();
        raum wohnzimmer = new raum();
        raum kueche = new raum();
        raum schlafzimmer = new raum();
        wohnung.rooms[0] = keller;
        wohnung.rooms[1] = wohnzimmer;
        wohnung.rooms[2] = kueche;
        wohnung.rooms[3] = schlafzimmer;
        keller.raumname = "Keller";
        wohnzimmer.raumname = "Wohnzimmer";
        kueche.raumname = "Küche";
        schlafzimmer.raumname = "Schlafzimmer";
        for (uint i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wohnung beinhaltet jetzt " + *MISSING CODE PART, I WANT TO GET THE .raumname out of the object array from wohnung.room*); 
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: why are `s_raumname`, `o_nebenraum` and `o_rooms` static? Why is `o_nebenraum` of type `object[]` instead of `raum[]`? Why do you use arrays instead of List?

Comment: You should access them anywhere, o_nebenraum is now raum[] and I also use Lists now as stated bewlow :)

Comment: if `s_raumname` is static, this will result in a "strange" behavior, that all rooms will have the same name (the last one that is assigned - in this case "Schlafzimmer")

Comment: You are right, thats why it isn't static anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(in the for Loop):

```
Console.WriteLine("Wohnung beinhaltet jetzt " + (wohnung.rooms[i] as raum).raumname );
```

You would be better off using generics though in which case the class level would now look like:

```
class level 
{     
    static List<raum> o_rooms = new List<raum>();
    public List<raum> rooms
    {         
        get         {             return o_rooms;          }         
        set         {             o_rooms = value;         }     
    }
}
```

and the `for` loop can be replaced with a `foreach` loop as follows:

```
foreach(raum room in wohnung.rooms)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wohnung beinhaltet jetzt " + room.raumname ); 
}
```

Comment: Easiest method for me and 100% understandable at the moment :)

Comment: if `List<raum> o_rooms` is static, every instance of `level` will have the same rooms. By the way: Your public property has no name...

Answer (score 2):

You have to use generic typed list `List<T>` ([See on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)) instead of array, in this case you'll have the *indexed* access for the *typed* list elements

So instead of:

```
static object[] o_rooms = new object[100];      
public object[] rooms
```

Use:

```
static IList<raum> o_rooms = new List<Raum>(100);      
public IList<raum> rooms
```